# PL/SQL - better to fetch value of a constant in other package or call it each time

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is a performance / efficiency question:
I have a package containing hundreds of global variables to be used throughout my PL/SQL solution. Is it better to fetch a value of the variable at the declaration stage once, or rather call it by its name each time the variable is referenced?
For example, in my global definitions package, I have a variable called "gv_SuperUserRole" which has a value assigned to it.
In my application, is it better to declare this as

```
local_var := glabal_package.gv_SuperUserRole
```

and then use the local_var throughout my current procedure like so:

```
if x < local_var
```

Or rather call the global variable like so:

```
if x < glabal_package.gv_SuperUserRole
```

Is the variable stored in the definitions package easily accessible by the local procedure or rather additional overhead has to take place each time I call the variable?

Comment: There is a programming difference. If your procedure uses `glabal_package.gv_SuperUserRole` in its code then it's guaranteed to be using a constant value. But if your code uses `local_var` there you open the door to the program changing the variable and hence the value being used. Using the package variable is more expressive of intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no difference. As soon as you invoke a package for the first time, the **whole** package is loaded into memory so there's no additional disk I/O when you reference anything from that package.

So, whether you assign a global variable value to a local variable and then work with a local variable, or you use only a global variable, there shouldn't be any (significant) difference.

Here's an example; I hope it makes sense.

```
SQL> create or replace package global_package as
  2    gv_superuserrole number := 1000;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test1 as
  2    local_var number := global_package.gv_superuserrole;
  3    l_sum     number := 0;
  4  begin
  5    if 100 < local_var then
  6       l_sum := l_sum + 1;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test2 as
  2    l_sum number := 0;
  3  begin
  4    if 100 < global_package.gv_superuserrole then
  5       l_sum := l_sum + 1;
  6    end if;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test1;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test2;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL>
SQL> -- Once again --------------------------------
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test1;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test2;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL>
SQL> -- Once again --------------------------------
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test1;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test2;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
SQL>
SQL> -- Once again --------------------------------
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test1;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      p_test2;
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
```

Comment: This could be a good test case but the loops and times are too small.  There are many irrelevant factors that could cause a performance difference between 0.01 seconds and 0.05 seconds.

Comment: Yes. This is an example. The OP, if patient enough, could add a zero or two and run it again.

Comment: Littlefoot, this is exactly what I needed to see!

Answer (score 1):

In principle, declaring and populating another variable is an overhead as it’s another processing step and requires another memory location to be allocated, although in practice I doubt this will be measurable.

Referring to the original definitions directly will be better from a code readability point of view, as you won’t have to remember that `local_var` comes from `global_package.gv_SuperUser_Role`.

There could be a big difference in the program logic, if `global_package.gv_SuperUser_Role` is really a variable as its name implies rather than a constant, as your local copy might ensure that the value won’t change during processing. Or if `local_var` is a variable then it might just use `global_package.gv_SuperUser_Role` as an initial value and update it to something different in a later step.

If I had to support this code, I’d be a lot happier if `global_package` contained constants. I’ve known global variables make code virtually impossible to understand and predict.

Comment: In this case the global package is simply a huge list of constants The package was created for code consolidation, but I was afraid that using it is not as efficient.

Comment: Good to hear, although generally a `v_` prefix indicates a variable, so again from a support/maintenance/readability point of view, `global_package.gv_SuperUser_Role` does not suggest that the value is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`if x < glabal_package.gv_SuperUserRole`
Is better than

```
local_var := glabal_package.gv_SuperUserRole
if x < local_var
```

But as the previous answer mentioned, it does not make a lot of difference performance wise in the code execution.